# Adding data in MongoEngine + Django

Tags: django, mongodb, django-models, mongoengine

I'm using django+mongoengine.

Im following the official tutorial but I have no idea how to introduce data in my database.

I don't know if I had to use django console, python console or mongodb

Here is the ling with the tutorial: [MongoengineTutorial](http://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#adding-data-to-our-tumblelog)

Using mongo I find the following error

```
(reb_env)root@marcproves:/REBORN/REBORN_PROJ# mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
connecting to: test
Server has startup warnings: 
Tue Apr  1 05:37:35.300 [initandlisten] 
Tue Apr  1 05:37:35.300 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: You are running in OpenVZ. This is known to be broken!!!
Tue Apr  1 05:37:35.301 [initandlisten] 
> ross = User(email='ross@example.com', first_name='Ross', last_name='Lawley').save()
Tue Apr  1 06:22:38.046 ReferenceError: User is not defined
> show dbs
local   0.03125GB
reborn  0.203125GB
> use reborn
switched to db reborn
> ross = User(email='ross@example.com', first_name='Ross', last_name='Lawley').save()
Tue Apr  1 06:22:51.791 ReferenceError: User is not defined
```

I just created an app and added the following code from the tutorial:

```
  GNU nano 2.2.6                             File: models.py                                                                  

//from django.db import models
from mongoengine import *
# Create your models here.
class User(Document):
    email = StringField(required=True)
    first_name = StringField(max_length=50)
    last_name = StringField(max_length=50)

class Post(Document):
    title = StringField(max_length=120, required=True)
    author = ReferenceField(User, reverse_delete_rule=CASCADE)
    tags = ListField(StringField(max_length=30))
    comments = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Comment))
    meta = {'allow_inheritance': True}

class TextPost(Post):
    content = StringField()

class ImagePost(Post):
    image_path = StringField()

class LinkPost(Post):
    link_url = StringField()

class Comment(EmbeddedDocument):
    content = StringField()
    name = StringField(max_length=120)
```

UPDATED: Runned in django shell

```
(reb_env)root@marcproves:/REBORN/REBORN_PROJ# python manage.py shell
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2013, 20:03:06) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from mongoengine import *
>>> connect('reborn')
MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
>>> ross = User(email='ross@example.com', first_name='Ross', last_name='Lawley').save()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'User' is not defined
>>>
```

And the same error, User is not defined, what should I do ?

Comment: May be I'm loosing something basic but i can't handle this. Could anybody give me a more detailed tutorial than the official ? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I finally solve the problem.

In models I had to declare how the db is, as always...

(models.py)

```
# Create your models here.
from mongoengine import *
class User(Document):
    email = StringField(required=True)
    first_name = StringField(max_length=50)
    last_name = StringField(max_length=50)
class Comment(EmbeddedDocument):
    content = StringField()
    name = StringField(max_length=120)


class Post(Document):
    title = StringField(max_length=120, required=True)
    author = ReferenceField(User)
    tags = ListField(StringField(max_length=30))
    comments = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Comment))
    meta = {'allow_inheritance': True}

class TextPost(Post):
    content = StringField()

class ImagePost(Post):
    image_path = StringField()

class LinkPost(Post):
    link_url = StringField()
```

In views.py(or python console either)....

```
from django.shortcuts import render 
# Create your views here.
from django.http import HttpResponse  
from game.models import *  //Import the models 
from mongoengine import * //Import things like connect

def testview(request):  
    connect('reborn')//Connect to DB
    //Let's add some data!
    article = User(email = 'test@title.com',first_name = 'test content')
    article.save()
    return HttpResponse("SAVED")
```

Answer (score 0):

Those examples are Python code. You run them in the Django shell, or in your app's code.

Comment: This doesen't help me at all,I tried before post it, anyway the .save() sounds like mongo but didn't run either.

Comment: Your question was specifically "where do I run this?", which I've answered. And `.save()` is Python/Django.

Comment: Ok, sorry then, may you are in the right way but mongo/python continues dropping me an error.

Comment: As Daniel says you need to run the python code in a python environment.  You're example above is trying to run python in the mongo (js) shell!  If you are getting a python error - please update the question with that error.

Answer (score 0):

Try type `import * from app.models` in shell before adding data.

Comment: haha, sorry i'd made a typo. I mean 'from app.models import *'

Comment: Yes, anyway I tested the other wat round but it didn't work, anyway I got the solution.